# Ensure users of an app are present, at all times, in a demo version of the app

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, synchronization

I'm creating a version of an existing symfony php application which is to be used as sandbox, i.e. a sort of demo version of the app.
The two apps will use separate mysql schemas on the same server.
The two schemas are identical and the sandbox schema will be dropped and recreated with data from the main app at the start of each day.
During the day, users may be created/updated in the main app and I want these changes to be reflected in the sandbox app immediately - so I need to copy changes from about three related tables whenever they're changed in the main app.

I've considered creating triggers on the required tables in the main schema, but i'm having little luck finding examples of AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE trigger_body that do something like.

I've considered modifying the Doctrine objects associated with the three tables to save via a separate Doctrine_Connection (for the sandbox dsn).

I've considered extending the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin in the main app to provide authentication for both apps, but this would still require a transfer of data from the three tables.

Is there any method I've not considered here? Which method would be best?

Comment: Would syncing both databases work for you? It should be easily done if they are both in the same server. And it would also take care of the need to sync each morning.

Comment: do you mean replication? constantly updating the sandbox db with changes made to the main db? i'd certainly be up for trying this (though there may be some tables I wouldn't want to sync in this way), but as I understand it, replication isn't possible within the same server. am i wrong?

Comment: yes. I mean replication. The most common implementation is to replicate between 2 different servers. However you can have two instances of MySQL in the same server and they can replicate the same way as if they were in different servers.

Comment: thank you, jdias. regrettably, I cannot run another instance of mysql on this box, so I guess replication is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following in the sandbox codebase:

- Implemented an alternative validator to sfGuardValidatorUser and pointed app.yml to this class with the auth_user_validator key.
- Implemented a private validator method _checkMainApp which is called with the user-supplied credentials if the user is not found in the sandbox user table. It does the following:

  - set-up an ad-hoc connection to the main app db (working around some bugs [symfony](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/7676), [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-740))
  - query the main db for the user (and then restore the original db connection)
  - if user is found and the password is good, perform a deep copy of the object
  - finally, only the user and its profile should be copied and any other related object (available via the deep copied user) should be located in the sandbox db and should replace the existing relations - this is what _fixCopiedRelations does (in a rather cumbersome fashion).

```
# lib/validator/yiValidatorUserSandbox.class.php
    protected function doClean($values)
    {
        // snip

        // don't allow to sign in with an empty username
        if ($username)
        {
            // snip

            // user exists?
            if ($user) {
                // password is ok?
                // snip
            } else if ($user = $this->_checkMainApp($username, $password)) {
                return array_merge($values, array('user' => $user));
            }
        }
        // snip
    }

    private function _checkMainApp($username, $password)
    {
        $sandConn     = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')->getConnection();
        $readOnlyConn = Doctrine_Manager::connection(
            'mysql://root@localhost/maindb', 'readonly' # readonly is only the conn name, not its state
        );
        $user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardUser')
            ->getAllUserDetailsUsingConnection($username, $readOnlyConn);
        Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->closeConnection($readOnlyConn);
        Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setCurrentConnection($sandConn->getName());
        if (   $user instanceof sfGuardUser && $user->getIsActive()
            && $user->checkPassword($password)
        ) {
            $sandboxUser = $user->copy(true);
            $this->_fixCopiedRelations($sandboxUser);
            $sandboxUser->setPasswordHash($user['password']);
            $sandboxUser->save($sandConn);
            return $sandboxUser;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function _fixCopiedRelations(Doctrine_Record $rec)
    {
        $rel = $rec->getReferences();
        foreach ($rel as $name => $related) {
            if ($name == 'Responsibilities') {
                $coll = new Doctrine_Collection('Client');
                foreach ($related as $client) {
                    $o = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Client')->findOneByCode($client['code']);
                    if ($o instanceof Client == false) {
                        throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                            'Cannot find related object in the sandbox database, therefore not copying sfGuardUser to the sandbox.'
                        );
                    }
                    $coll->add($o);
                }
                $rec[$name] = $coll;
            } else if ($name == 'Groups' || $name == 'Permissions') {
                $coll = new Doctrine_Collection(($name == 'Groups' ? 'sfGuardGroup' : 'sfGuardPermission'));
                foreach ($related as $instance) {
                    $o = Doctrine_Core::getTable(($name == 'Groups' ? 'sfGuardGroup' : 'sfGuardPermission'))->findOneByName($instance['name']);
                    if ($o instanceof Doctrine_Record == false) {
                        throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                            'Cannot find related object in the sandbox database, therefore not copying sfGuardUser to the sandbox.'
                        );
                    }
                    $coll->add($o);
                }
                $rec[$name] = $coll;
            } else if ($name == 'Profile') {
                $this->_fixCopiedRelations($related);
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                    'Method does not know how to copy this related object to the sandbox, therefore not copying sfGuardUser to the sandbox'
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

It's worth noting that, in order to prevent _fixCopiedRelations from failing, I have to make sure that any related objects that exists in the main db also exist in the sandbox db, but the creation of new such objects is very limited so it's not really a problem in this case.

I'm not particularly enamoured with the solution, but it works in this limited context and it's good enough.